# Using the values in a dictionary if the key matches a 3D lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so I'm starting working with dictionary and tuples and I have a problem, I have 3D list with a bunch of coordinates and also a dictionary whose keys matches the coordinates in my 3d list, what I need it's that if a `key` and a coordinate matches,then sum the `values` of the dict, this is an example.

```
from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen

mylist = [[[2, 3], [3, 4]], [[2, 3], [2, 4]], [[2, 4], [3, 4]]]

d = {(2, 3): 32, (3, 4): 14, (2, 4): 38}
```

So in the first list of `mylist` I have the coordinates `[2, 3], [3, 4]` whose `values` are 32 and 14 in `d` and if I sum them the output should be 46, for the second list I have `[2, 3], [2, 4]` and the `values` are 32 and 38, so my output is 70 and the same for the last list, my desired output should be:

```
output = [46, 70, 52]
```

I thought about change the coordinates of my list to tuples, but maybe I'm creating unnecessary copies and the problem it's more easy that it looks like, so if you can point me out to the right direction or give me a reference I will appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use tuple() to convert to tuple and list() to convert to list().
Try this:

```
output = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    cnt = 0
    for inner_list in sub_list:
        cnt += d[tuple(inner_list)]
    output.append(cnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[d.get(tuple(f), 0) + d.get(tuple(s), 0) for f, s in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[46, 70, 52]
```

Comment: Thank you! It does work for this example, but the list and the dict can have more elements, but I see what you doing, so I think I can generalized, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
[(d[(t[0][0], t[0][1])]+d[(t[1][0], t[1][1])]) for t in mylist]
```